# Camel Iterator or How to use Camel Splitter but keep body unchanged

Tags: iterator, apache-camel

I want to iterate String with a delimiter "," and then send message to several endpoint. The problem is if I use Splitter, it would replace the body content of my message.

```
from("switchyard://ICamelServiceProcess")
.process(new Processor() {
String recipients = "abc";
recipients += "," + "bcd";
exchange.getIn().setHeader("recipients", recipients);
}
.to("switchyard://ICamelServiceRoute");
```

In Service ICamelServiceRoute, I want to iterate through header.recipients value with delimiter "," and then create a file with a named of each iteration.

Could you please tell me some solution.
Thank you.

Comment: You should be able to do this with a [recipient list](http://camel.apache.org/recipient-list.html).

Comment: I did take a look at recipient list, routing slip, splitter. The problem with recipient is I must create before-hand many services. Now I try to use recipient list point to the same service. Like this:
recipients += "," + "switchyard://ICamelServiceRoute?operationName=routeMessage";
The different between recipient is to use different parameter. But I dont know how to pass parameter. Could you tell me how?

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question. I understood that you would like to create a varying number of files, the file name representing a "recipient", all files with the same contents, the contents being the body of your exchange. Is that not correct?

Comment: That's correct. Until now, I have no clues to solve this. Can you help me, please?

Comment: So why does the recipient list not work for you? Is it because you need to do things in switchyard?

Comment: After many hours trying many things, I realized my sillinest. Thanks Ralf, I can solve this problem.

Comment: Kindly update the answer you fix that will useful for others.

Answer (score 0):

You can save the original body in a exchange property before the splitter, and restore it from the property when finish splitter. With Camel 2.15 or latter

```
<setProperty propertyName="originalBody">
    <simple>${body}</simple>
</setPropery>
<split>
    <!-- Splitter function -->
</split>
<setBody>
    <simple>${exchageProperty[originalBody]}</simple>
</setBody>
```

All exchange properties will be deleted when finish the camel context execution. Note that you can save Java Object in exchange properties, but only until the camel context ending